# Similar questions after I post an ANSWER

Tags: feature-request

After I post an *answer*, it would be great to show similar questions that might be answered with the same response (or be merged, etc).

Comment: Define "similar questions".

Comment: And why would these similar questions be displayed *after* an answer? They are displayed before. If the answering person didn't look at them before, why would they after?

Comment: Are you planning to copy and paste your answer to more questions, instead of just closing them as duplicates?

Comment: @Wooble OP appears to be _very_ new to SO/SE, I don't think he's aware of our dupe philosophy yet.

Comment: whoops -- by "merging" I meant follow the recommended duplication process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you spot a question where you feel all you need to do to answer it is to copy paste one of your earlier answers, then please consider flagging it as a duplicate of the earlier question instead. Copy pasting exactly the same answer on multiple questions is generally frowned upon, and your answers may be removed.

That said, on every question page there's a list of related questions in the sidebar. That's good enough for finding questions that revolve around the same topics of the question you're viewing (or answering).

Comment: So the idea is to reduce friction and make it easier to spot other questions that would benefit from the answer (and most likely would benefit from being flagged as a dup, as you and some other folks have suggested). If the sidebar is effective at doing that, then let it be, but my guess is that there is room for improvement.